# How to calculating SUM of (quantity*price) from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have this two following tables:

**Order Table**

[image]

**Product Table**

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the subtotal price for each product (quantity*price) then SUM the TOTAL value for the entire order.

Thanks, Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to show your code. The question as it is now is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a rather basic `join` and `group by` query.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I know its easy but I'm not very good with mysql queries.

Comment: @decltype_auto Looks like someone is getting bit annoyed because I need help with my SQL. You should change your hobby you boring person not me ant you can't tell people to change their hobby you loser. At least I have a life unlike you who I bet have a very boring life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if table names are correct and try this:

```
SELECT o.order_number, o.item_quantity, p.price,(o.item_quantity * p.price) AS subtotal, SUM( o.item_quantity * p.price) AS total
FROM order AS o
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON product_number = idproduct_detail;
```

With this I am connecting each order with the relative product then selecting item_quantity and price and SUM the product of them.

Comment: Please, Fill your question with the required code